# What does "Place your man" mean?

Tags: meaning

> '"Ver-r-ry good," said he. "For that I shall have much pleasure to
>   kill you now and here. Monsieur Gamm,"--another bow to Jerry--"you
>   will please lend him your pistol, or he shall have mine. I give you my
>   word I know not which is best; and if he will choose a second from his
>   friends over there"--another bow to our drunken yokels at the
>   gate--"we will commence."
>
> '"That's fair enough," said Jerry. "Tom Dunch, you owe it to the
>   Doctor to be his second. **Place your man.**" '"No," said Tom. "No mixin'
>   in gentry's quarrels for me." And he shook his head and went out, and
>   the others followed him.

This is from "The Marklake witches " in "Rewards  and Fairies" by Kipling.
 http://pinkmonkey.com/dl/library1/digi300.pdf

I thik this is about a duel.
What does "Place your man" mean?

I am glad if some one kindly teach me.

Answer (score 6):

When the custom was to settle serious conflicts among men by a [*duel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duel) with pistols, as during the era of the Napoleonic Wars (1803–1815) in which Kipling's story takes place, the accepted etiquette was that each of the combatants was represented by a *second* (see definition 15 at [*Dictionary.com*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/second)) who was the duellist's representative in assuring that the duel was fought in conditions that were fair to both parties.

The [*Code Duello*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_duello) or "laws of the duel", as it was interpreted when pistols superseded swords as the weapons of choice, required that each second position his deullist at a position determined in advance for each party, and the usual command uttered at this stage was:

> Place your man.

This is attested in numerous fictional accounts of duels in the period, as [*here,*](https://books.google.com/books?id=pqlUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=etiquette+of+dueling+%22place+your+man%22&source=bl&ots=3EhAqyHwer&sig=p8xgBF7IMwB4uMDwAuir0CadCho&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGtp2eotzPAhUKWD4KHdubASwQ6AEIJDAD#v=onepage&q=%22place%20your%20man%22&f=false) and also in later factual accounts, as [*here.*](http://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/8814741)

Comment: P.E.Dant--Thank you so much for your detailed answer. Now I understand about duel and the system of second so well.

Comment: @HiroshiInagaki Your gratitude is appreciated and we are happy to be of assistance.